# "Dysfunction" as a verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, word-usage

I wonder if it is possible to use the noun "dysfunction" as a verb.

It is certainly a noun, but in general use it seems to mean something far more awful and much less technical than "malfunction".  It might be useful, in certain instances, to use it as a verb, at least colloquially, in order to emphasize just how badly something is malfunctioning.  Has anyone seen this?

E.g., a graduate thesis in family psychology discussing common causes for the breakdown of a family unit:

> This tends to cause a family to dysfunction and create animosity among siblings and spouses.

Comment: I can't find any dictionary that says *dysfunction* is ever a verb. Whereas, *malfunction* is listed as an intransitive verb. I would recommend using *malfunction* instead of *dysfunction* if you need a verb, especially in a thesis. If you insist on using the word *dysfunction* instead of *malfunction*, you could reword your sentence to use it as a noun: *This tends to cause dysfunction in a family, creating animosity among siblings and spouses.*

Comment: @JLG, thanks. I should clarify that I'm not writing a paper, and I wasn't planning on using the word. I was just thinking about it and gave an example that came to mind.

Comment: See [this blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/the-give-that-keeps-on-gifting-the-protean-nature-of-english-words-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/) for a discussion of the blurring of roles among parts of speech.

Comment: *Friend* as a verb is nothing new. Housman's *"And I will friend you, if I may, // In the dark and cloudy day."* appeared in 1896. Shakespeare wrote *"And what so poor a man as Hamlet is // May do t' express his love and friending to you"*. And *Merriam-Webster* says the use of *friend* as a verb is attested in the 13th century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using *dysfunction* as a verb. Nobody else does, so you'd either come across as an idiosyncratic maverick, or a non-native speaker.

To a considerable extent, *dysfunction/malfunction* can be defined as synonyms, but in practice *dysfunction* tends to be used in medical/sociological contexts, while *malfunction* is more likely in technological contexts (plus it's the default for all other contexts).

I don't think there's any justification for OP's assumption that *dysfunction* somehow implies a more extreme form of *malfunction*. Okay - most people would agree a dysfunctional family is worse than a malfunctioning hard drive, but don't forget the [Apollo 13 malfunction](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/ap13acc.html).

It's not obvious to me there's any real *need* to use *dysfunction* as a verb. Obviously I'm biased against OP's example usage simply because "that's not how we say it", but it also seems to me that there's something slightly "oxymoronic" about referring to *a family* collectively (so it can act as the subject of the verb) when semantically it's *not* a complete unit, acting as a single entity.

In short, English is indeed something of a "free-for-all" for native speakers in certain respects, but you really need to know the rules before you deliberately break them. And this context, that's in the sense of [as a rule](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/As+a+rule), not [rule of law](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Rule+of+Law,+the).

Comment: Excellent response, and thanks for calling me an idiosyncratic maverick. I like that a lot better than idiot. ;-) I wish I could +2.

Comment: @Seth J: Well, your profile doesn't give a location, or say whether you're a native speaker or not (though if you're *not*, you do a damned fine impersonation of one! :), so I thought it best to be diplomatic. In this specific case, if it weren't trivial to recast along the lines suggested by JLG, I'd simply put "dysfunction" in quotes to indicate a deliberate non-standard usage. But I think the general rule would be to only do this when there's no easy alternative. Maybe I should add that to the answer.

Comment: How's my impression of a _non_-native speaker?

Comment: @Seth J: Not sure I can answer that! Which parts (if any) of what you've typed on this page represent your impression of a non-native speaker? You're surely not implying that only *non-native* speakers would gloss over the distinction between *impersonation* and *impression*? I'm not sure even I could make a meaningful distinction in the exact context of this comment thread (though I bet even some non-native speakers would be prepared to try and answer that one if I actually asked it as an ELU question! :)

Comment: Nah, I just mis-plagiarized you. I am a native speaker, and I like to play around with the rules for artistic purposes and personal enjoyment. I heavily criticize others, though, for doing the same - if they're not doing it right (in my opinion). That's probably why I haven't been active here before. It's dangerous territory for me.

Comment: @Seth J: ELU is dangerous territory for anyone who criticises a native speaker's choice of phrasing! I get hammered for it every now and then. I'm from the UK, so I'm seriously outnumbered by Americans, as well as being outgunned by the fact that most of the other high-rep users here know far more than me about language (I just hang out here a lot, so I answer lots of questions - my rep reflects that rather than my formal knowledge here).

Comment: "More than I."  See? I just couldn't help myself!

Comment: So - style guides at dawn, is it? :)

Answer (score -2):

It can be worded as 'it causes/caused family dysfunction'.

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking.